# How to merge several variables to create a new factor variable in R?

Tags: r, variables, merge

I have data from a survey. It comes from a question that looks like this:

```
Did you do any of the following activities during your PhD

                             Yes, paid by my school. Yes, paid by me.  No. 

Attended an internationl conference?
Bought textbooks?
```

The data is automatically saved in a spreadsheet in this way:

```
id conf.1 conf.2 conf.3 text.1 text.2 text.3

1    1                              1
2           1               1
3                   1       1
4                   1                    1
5
```

This means participant 1 attended a conference paid by her university; particiapnt 2 attended the conference paid by him, and participant 3 didn't go.

I want to merge conf.1, conf.2 and conf.3 and text.1, text.2 and text.3 in single variables

```
id new.conf new.text

1   1        2
2   2        1
3   3        1
4   3        3

where the number now respresents the categories of the survey question

Thanks for your help
```

Comment: That's a reshape not a merge.  Try `reshape` (base R), `reshapeasy` (taRifx package), or the `reshape2` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state whether or not each set of questions can have multiple answers. If so, this approach may not work for you. If that's the case, I suggest making your question more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) before moving forward. With that caveat out of the way, give this a whirl:

```
library(reshape2)
#recreate your data
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                  conf.1 = c(1,rep(NA,4)),
                  conf.2 = c(NA,1, rep(NA,3)),
                  conf.3 = c(NA,NA,1,1, NA),
                  text.1 = c(NA,1,1,NA,NA),
                  text.2 = c(1, rep(NA,4)),
                  text.3 = c(rep(NA,3),1, NA))

#melt into long format
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "id")
#Split on the "."
dat.m[, c("variable", "val")] <- with(dat.m, colsplit(variable, "\\.", c("variable", "val")))
#Subset out only the complete cases
dat.m <- dat.m[complete.cases(dat.m),]
#Cast back into wide format
dcast(id ~ variable, value.var = "val", data = dat.m)
#-----
  id conf text
1  1    1    2
2  2    2    1
3  3    3    1
4  4    3    3
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base method which will cope with missing values:

```
confvars <- c("conf.1","conf.2","conf.3")
textvars <- c("text.1","text.2","text.3")

which.sub <- function(x) {
maxsub <- apply(dat[x],1,which.max)
maxsub[(lapply(maxsub,length)==0)] <- NA
return(unlist(maxsub))
}

data.frame(
id = dat$id,
conf = which.sub(confvars),
text = which.sub(textvars)
)
```

Result:

```
  id conf text
1  1    1    2
2  2    2    1
3  3    3    1
4  4    3    3
5  5   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question: is it possible to convert the reshaped table to a table for Latex showing the names of each level (e.g 1=sponsored by my institution; 2=sponsored by a different institution; 3=No)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is very straightforward and I use it a lot.
Let's use the same dataframe Chase did above.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                  conf.1 = c(1,rep(NA,4)),
                  conf.2 = c(NA,1, rep(NA,3)),
                  conf.3 = c(NA,NA,1,1, NA),
                  text.1 = c(NA,1,1,NA,NA),
                  text.2 = c(1, rep(NA,4)),
                  text.3 = c(rep(NA,3),1, NA))
```

Now we start by replacing the NAs with zeros.

```
dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0
```

Multiplying each column by a different number allows us to simply calculate the new variables.

```
dat <- transform(dat, conf=conf.1 + 2*conf.2 + 3*conf.3,
                      text=text.1 + 2*text.2 + 3*text.3)
```

Let's recode the zeros in our new variables (or here for the whole dataset) to NA and were done.

```
dat[dat == 0] <- NA 

> dat
  id conf.1 conf.2 conf.3 text.1 text.2 text.3 conf text
1  1      1     NA     NA     NA      1     NA    1    2
2  2     NA      1     NA      1     NA     NA    2    1
3  3     NA     NA      1      1     NA     NA    3    1
4  4     NA     NA      1     NA     NA      1    3    3
5  5     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA   NA   NA
```